# Flask-SQLAlchemy query many-to-many tagging with multiple requred tags

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy, tagging

I have defined models:

```
tags = db.Table('tags',
                db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id')),
                db.Column('photo_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('photo.id')),
                )


class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(32), unique=True)


class Photo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sha1sum = db.Column(db.LargeBinary(20), unique=True)
    ...
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tags,
                           backref=db.backref('photos', lazy='dynamic'))
```

In flask controller/view I get array of input tags for example `['summer', 'selfie', ...]`.

Questions:

1. Efficient query for photos which contain all of the requested tags?
2. How can it be extended for search with incomplete tags such as `['summ', 'elfi', ...]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might not be the most *efficient* (if you have many tags to search), but very *readable* way to compose the query:

```
input_tags = ['selfie', 'summer']
q = db.session.query(Photo)
for tag in input_tags:
    q = q.filter(Photo.tags.any(Tag.name == tag))
```

For incomplete use `startswith(..)` instead of `==`:

```
input_tags = ['sum', 'fu']
q = db.session.query(Photo)
for tag in input_tags:
    q = q.filter(Photo.tags.any(Tag.name.startswith(tag)))
```

Comment: Your solution is great. I just replaced `startswith()` with `contains()`. Big thank you.